# UDPROS unrecoverable behavior on dropped packets

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, topic-tools, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running a simple UDPROS throttle topic_tools, when a packet is dropped in the middle of the message, it looks like it complains but doesn't recover.  I expected it to complain and then skip to the next message, but it looks like it keeps looking for the same packet number, even in the next message.  Then in the rosnode info, it appears to drop the connection entirely and give up and I have to restart the node.

This is occuring on fuerte and electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47706/udpros-unrecoverable-behavior-on-dropped-packets/) by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To me, this sounds like a bug. Please file a ticket (best including a reproducible test case) at the corresponding bug tracker. For roscpp, it should be [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues) now.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0